# Problem about setting jupyter notebook server in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda, Python 3 and Jupyter notebooks on an AWS EC2 instance.

Instance details:
Ubuntu 16.04, already set up a port for Jupyter notebook in the security group:
Custom TCP Rule 8888 Anywhere
Python version: Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
python-dateutil (2.8.1)

I created a Jupyter notebook config file:

```
c = get_config()
# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline' # if you want plotting support always in your notebook
# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' # location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.key' # location of your certificate key
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  # so that the ipython notebook does not open a browser by default
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:68c136a5b064...' # the encrypted password you generated above
```

I also set my Tunnels in the Putty as `port:8888` destination: `localhost:8888`.

However, when I type:
`$ jupyter notebook`

It prompts out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/jupyter", line 7, in
from jupyter_core.command import main
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/init.py", line 1, in
from .version import version_info, version
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/version.py", line 21
suffix = f'.dev{version_info.serial}'
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Any reason you are using old ubuntu? Also just try with default notebook settings, without any custom setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the lab instruction online so I used ubuntu 16.04. I found out that the error is because the python version for execution is too old for the jupyter package.

Comment: Hey Marcin, I think you misunderstood what I mean. The problem is caused by the old version of python since the execution path of python is not properly direct to the anaconda one. It directed to the original python in the root with the older version. I think that may be a mistake about the online lab.

Comment: No problem and thanks for letting me know. You can answer your question with more details if you want.